# How to add GET parameter based on user input?

Tags: android, http, get

I'm making an application that takes user input, and I want it to pass it as a GET parameter to an HTTP request.

My question is, how do I pass the input to the GET request?

For example say the input was `10`, the request URL should be:

```
http://example.com/?no=10&otherparam=some_stuff_here
```

I know how to make a GET request but I don't know how to add parameter from user input

Answer (score 0):

Find your edit text:

```
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext_id); //replace with your ID
```

Get the user input:

```
String input = et.getText().toString();
```

---

Now you have the user input in a variable called `input`. HTTP GET parameters are just parameters added to the URL.

Assume you have this URL:

```
http://example.com/search.php?keywords=some_keywords
```

If you want to add, say, `language` parameter to that, you just append that to the URL like:

```
http://example.com/search.php?keywords=some_keywords&language=English
```

---

Now open a connection to the server with the desired param

```
URLConnection con = new URL("http://example.com/?exampleparam=" + input).openConnection();
```

And use Input/Ouput Streams to receive and send from/to your server:

```
con.getInputStream();
con.getOutputstream();
```

**Note**

Since you are on Android, you can't do network operations on main UI thread, open and start new thread like:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Run your network operations here
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //Update UI here
            }
        });
    }
});
t.start();
```

You can also use AsyncTask too

Comment: I Do not need the server response, just making the request is enough. Thanks for quick reply,let me try.